# hibernate scrollable result fetch immediatelly all rows in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-connector

Our applications may run over multiple DB depending on customer infrastructure.
We use Hibernate orm, so we can deploy our applications over various RDBMS.

We notice that we have an abnormal consumption of memory in all the environments where a MySql database is used.

Analyzing the problem we see that it raises when we use scrollable result.
At the opposite of other environnements (SQL server, Oracle,....) it looks like the scrollable result in MySql fetch immediately all the results of the query.

As far as I know and I have seen in Oracle and SQL Server when you use scrollable result a cursor is open, and rows are fetched from the DB server only when `next()` method is called. All our cursors are `FORWARD_ONLY.

I think that the cause is the MySql-jdbc-connector that doesn't handle correctly the scrollable result. 
Is that correct?
Can I have the scrollable result working correctly on MySql? And, if yes, how?
Thanks in advance to anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes apparently MySQL caches ResultSet data by default because it's the most efficent way for it
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html

> By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory.
>   In most cases this is the most efficient way to operate and, due to
>   the design of the MySQL network protocol, is easier to implement.

you can try: `query.setFetchSize()`, it will give the underlying jdbc hint about your requirment.
But it all depends on the driver, some may actually just ignore it and proceed to fetch everything